# Using a loop to awk between two patterns

Tags: unix, awk, while-loop

I have a large database (database.csv) with entries in the following format:

```
SOME_ID_NUMBER
Some delimited columns of data here
More delimited columns of data here
Tonsof delimited columns of data here
#########
SOME_ID_NUMBER_2
Other delimited columns of data here
Cool delimited columns of data here
Awesome delimited columns of data here
Extra delimited columns of data here
#########
OTHER_ID_NAMES
Lame delimited columns of data here
Boring delimited columns of data here
Okay delimited columns of data here
#########
```

The entries start with an entry name, then several lines (varying numbers) of delimited data, then terminates with a line of '#' characters

I also have a large list of patterns in another file (patterns.csv) containing entries such as:

```
Some_ID_NUMBER
OTHER_ID_NAMES
ID_NOT_IN_LIST
```

I would like to extract the entries from the database file that match the patterns in the pattern file. Here is the desired example output using the data from above.

```
SOME_ID_NUMBER
Some delimited columns of data here
More delimited columns of data here
Tonsof delimited columns of data here
#########
OTHER_ID_NAMES
Lame delimited columns of data here
Boring delimited columns of data here
Okay delimited columns of data here
#########
```

Or an even better output:

```
SOME_ID_NUMBER Some delimited columns of data here
SOME_ID_NUMBER More delimited columns of data here
SOME_ID_NUMBER Tonsof delimited columns of data here
OTHER_ID_NAMES Lame delimited columns of data here
OTHER_ID_NAMES Boring delimited columns of data here
OTHER_ID_NAMES Okay delimited columns of data here
ID_NOT_IN_LIST
```

Here is my attempt:

```
while read line
do
awk -v start="$line" -v last="#" '/^"start"/,/^"last"/' database.csv >>matches.csv
done<patterns.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS and ENDFILE:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR { patterns[toupper($0)]; next }
ENDFILE { RS=ORS="\n#########\n"; FS="\n" }
toupper($1) in patterns

$ gawk -f tst.awk patterns.csv database.csv
SOME_ID_NUMBER
Some delimited columns of data here
More delimited columns of data here
Tonsof delimited columns of data here
#########
OTHER_ID_NAMES
Lame delimited columns of data here
Boring delimited columns of data here
Okay delimited columns of data here
#########
```

.

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR { patterns[toupper($0)]; next }
ENDFILE { RS="\n#########\n"; FS="\n" }
toupper($1) in patterns {
    patterns[$1]++
    for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {
        print $1, $i
    }
}
END {
    for (pat in patterns) {
        if (patterns[pat] == 0) {
            print pat
        }
    }
}

$ gawk -f tst.awk patterns.csv database.csv
SOME_ID_NUMBER Some delimited columns of data here
SOME_ID_NUMBER More delimited columns of data here
SOME_ID_NUMBER Tonsof delimited columns of data here
OTHER_ID_NAMES Lame delimited columns of data here
OTHER_ID_NAMES Boring delimited columns of data here
OTHER_ID_NAMES Okay delimited columns of data here
ID_NOT_IN_LIST
```

See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice if you're ever tempted to write a shell loop again just to manipulate text.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Could you please explain some of your code (in tst.awk)? I am new to shell scripting and am having trouble understanding.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't think learning a tool/language from the bottom up by reading a bunch of examples is a good way to learn it - read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins. Jump to the sections on the language constructs I used first if that helps, but do at least skim the whole book to pick up the main ideas of the language. If you have some specific questions about the script I'll be happy to answer them.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I will do that.